# How to freeze selected weights in keras or tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras, keras-2

I am trying out something where I required to freeze some selected weights. Take this example

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Input

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(4,),activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3,name="hidden",activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

print(model.layers[1].get_weights()[0])
```

This will print the input to hidden layer weights.

```
# Weights input x hidden
# Freeze 2Rx3C and 4Rx2C
# 2Rx3C=0.14362943; 4Rx2C=-0.23868048
array([[-0.05557871,  0.10941017, -0.59108734],
       [ 0.37056673,  0.2968588 ,  0.14362943],
       [-0.05471832, -0.21425706,  0.6455065 ],
       [-0.7883829 , -0.23868048, -0.517396  ]], dtype=float32)
```

From this weight matrix I want to freeze values in `(2nd Row, 3rd Column)` and `(4th Row, 2nd Column)`, that is, **0.14362943** and **-0.23868048** respectively. I dont want to update these values on backprop. How can I freeze these selected weights?

Comment: Hi, Eka. Does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [tf.identity](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity), it is used when you want to explicitly transport tensor between devices.

```
matrixVariable = tf.Variable(<your matrix>)
matrixVariableSliced = matrixVariable[<sliced matrix>] #take out your required weights
matrixVariable_stop = tf.stop_gradient(tf.identity(matrixVariableSliced)) 
matrixVariable = tf.concat((matrixVariableSliced, matrixVariable_stop), axis=1)
```